# Why is my 1PPS GPS stratum-1 clock always ~100ms behind other ntp servers?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I am trying to set up a stratum-1 time server. I have a [Navisys GR-701](http://www.navisys.com.tw/products/GPS&GNSS_receivers/flyer/GR-701_flyer-150703.pdf) GPS which is capable sending a 1 PPS signal. According to the spec sheet and sources [such as this](http://catb.org/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html#_1pps_quality_issues), I am under the impression I should obtain ~1ms accuracy with ntpd. However, my `ntpq` output always looks similar to the following:

```
$ ntpq -pncrv
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
x127.127.22.0    .PPS.            0 l   10   16  377    0.000   -0.204   0.277
o127.127.20.0    .GPS.            0 l   11   16  377    0.000   -0.201   0.277
 us.pool.ntp.org .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 pool.ntp.org    .POOL.          16 p    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 132.163.96.2    .NIST.           1 u   42   64  377   41.279  103.302   0.576
 198.137.202.56  216.218.254.202  2 u   42   64  377   12.813  104.505   0.736
 96.244.96.19    192.168.10.254   2 u   39   64  377   83.023  101.028  19.775
 216.187.142.202 204.123.2.72     2 u   33   64  177   53.911  104.458   7.406
 69.10.161.7     204.26.59.157    3 u   36   64  177   23.968  104.162   3.718
 129.6.15.29     .NIST.           1 u   59   64   77   83.782  101.719   0.298
 204.2.134.164   199.233.236.226  3 u   38   64   37   12.489  103.279   3.668
 129.6.15.30     .NIST.           1 u   32   64   37   83.723  101.487   0.319
 108.61.73.244   128.59.0.245     2 u   40   64   37   94.283  109.618   4.261
 66.172.10.184   199.102.46.72    2 u   34   64   33   20.098  104.790   0.421
 72.5.72.15      162.213.2.253    2 u   33   64   37   12.271  103.247   0.163
 204.9.54.119    .CDMA.           1 u   29   64   17   61.895  102.250   1.371
 198.206.133.14  58.180.158.150   3 u   60   64    3   70.588  103.281   0.451
 129.250.35.250  249.224.99.213   2 u   60   64    3   12.579  102.302   0.611
 216.6.2.70      195.219.14.21    2 u   61   64    3   82.862  104.402   0.366
 198.55.111.50   45.79.111.114    3 u   56   64    3   22.114  104.099   0.728
 216.228.192.52  207.171.7.151    3 u   28   64    3   37.095   97.609   0.214
associd=0 status=04f8 leap_none, sync_uhf_radio, 15 events, no_sys_peer,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Mon Oct  9 10:54:36 UTC 2017 (1)",
processor="amd64", system="FreeBSD/11.1-RELEASE-p2", leap=00, stratum=1,
precision=-24, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=1.150, refid=GPS,
reftime=dda36229.ea4158ca  Tue, Oct 31 2017 13:57:13.915,
clock=dda36234.1c1f0bc5  Tue, Oct 31 2017 13:57:24.109, peer=28141, tc=4,
mintc=3, offset=-0.200797, frequency=53.398, sys_jitter=0.276969,
clk_jitter=0.014, clk_wander=0.008
```

ntpd.conf

```
tinker panic 0 
# Orphan mode stratum
tos orphan 12

# PPS Setup
server 127.127.22.0 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 prefer
fudge 127.127.22.0 flag3 0

# GPS Setup
server 127.127.20.0 mode 16 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 prefer
fudge 127.127.20.0 flag1 1 flag3 1


# Upstream Servers
server time-b-b.nist.gov iburst maxpoll 9
pool us.pool.ntp.org iburst maxpoll 9
pool pool.ntp.org iburst maxpoll 9


enable stats
statistics clockstats
statsdir /var/log/ntp
logconfig =syncall +clockall +sysall
driftfile /var/db/ntpd.drift
restrict default kod limited nomodify nopeer notrap
restrict -6 default kod limited nomodify nopeer notrap
restrict source kod limited nomodify notrap
interface ignore all
interface listen igb0
```

Is ntpd really saying my clock is ~100ms "behind" every other clock? If so, why is is so and what can I do about it?

Comment: You should include you ntp.conf and the output of `ntpq -pncrv`. I take it you are using a gps/pps puck that is connected via USB:(  

Aside from whatever else is in your ntp.conf I can tell you right away that you dont need 15 upstream servers. There is no need have two "pool us.ntp.org". Also you dont have a "stratum-0 clock", you have a stratum 1, albeit poorly functioning.

Comment: @dfc added more detailed info. I was just trying to get a bunch of other reference points for debugging purposes.

Comment: You might be triggering on the wrong side of the PPS signal.